# Dropzone Image Upload Dynamic URL

Tags: vue.js, dropzone.js, vue2-dropzone, vue-dropzone

I have added dropzone component in vue.

I want to change the image upload URL dynamically, see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I have also tried:


this.form.id

this.$form.id

form.id

$form.id


But does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have to do `this.form.id`